# Reuse a composite key for a child + a new field

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, composite-key

I use spring boot, with jpa (hibernate) and postgresql

I use composite key.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    private int year;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
}

public class SamplingsPK implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private int year;

    public SamplingsPK(Integer id, int year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.year=year;
    }

    private SamplingsPK(){

    } 

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        year = LocalDate.now().getYear();
    }
}   

@Entity
public class Samples {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "samples_id_seq", sequenceName = "samples_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "samples_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    private String sampleLetter;

    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")
        })
private Samplings sampling;

}
```

That work fine

Instead of having an sequence in samples, I would like to have a composite key... SamplingsPK + sampleLetter.

Is it possible to do it, how to save a sample?

Comment: Why? The sampling could already be uniquely identified with just the ID, since it's auto-generated. You make it more complex than necessary by adding a second field to the ID. And then you want a third thing to identify Sample. This clearly doesn't scale: the more you add entities, the larger your PKs will become, making the code convoluted, the tables much larger than necessary, the queries more complex and less efficient. Not to mention that since you use functional fields as part of IDs, you won't be able to change them, ever. Why not just stick to one auto-generated ID field per entity?

Comment: because client when to use year + sequence for it's primary key and add letter to this pk for sample

Comment: Well, you're the professional. If you were an architect, and the client asked you for a house without any foundation and where the roof is made of paper, wouldn't you consider it your duty to tell the client that this is really not a good idea?

Comment: composite key is not so complex, come on. in other application (not java) with composite key we do more then 50 insert second without problem... with this one that will be  a few insert a day... so performance is not a issue... query more complex? we use spring data so is mostly transparent...

Answer (score 1):

This is a "derived identity", so `Samples` could be mapped with an `@IdClass` like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")
    })
    private Samplings sampling;

    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;
}

public class SamplesPK {
    SamplingsPK sampling; // matches name of attribute and type of Samplings PK
    String sampleLetter; // matches name and type of attribute
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: interesting, just need to test how saving of sample will work